# Create a view, similar to mail list, inside a windows form for an outlook add-in

Tags: c#, email, outlook, outlook-addin

I'm trying to create an Outlook Add-in, where there will be a Windows form.  Inside that form will be a list of mail messages i.e. just a different view from the inbox.

I'm doing this for MS Outlook 2010/2013, using C# [VS 2010 Outlook 2010 Add-in].

I already tried exploring the following but it doesn't seem to suit or I'm missing something:

- Table view (It seems to apply only on an active explorer/inspector and not something showable/displayable inside a windows form.)
- Form region
- Outlook view control (I can't seem to find a reference to ViewCtl or AxMicrosoft)

I'm now thinking of just using something like a grid view and then fill it with the mail items.  But I'm wondering if there's better way than this and if anyone can point me where else to look?

Thanks :)

Comment: Is this just for a particular folder? Are you trying to display this in a separate window? Or *instead* of the view shown by Outlook?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand...

_Is this just for a particular folder?_ - I think yes, though the user can actually select which folders.

_Are you trying to display this in a separate window?_ - I think yes, since it's a separate windows form.

_Or instead of the view shown by Outlook?_ - I think no, default outlook window should stay as it is.  The view should only be for within the form.

Comment: If it is your own window, what prevents you from using a list view control and populating it with data in any way you see fit? If you do not like a list view, you can use one of literally hundreds C# grid controls.

Comment: That's my last resort.  I'm wishing it would appear similar in look to the email list in the default outlook window.  Outlook view control appears to do the job, but I can't make it work.

Comment: Of course, because it can only display the contents of a folder. It will not show your custom data.

Answer (score 0):

> now thinking of just using something like a grid view and then fill it with the mail items.

I don't think that keeping another list view (using the grid view control, for example) will be an easy task.

> Form region

They are for inspector windows only. You need to subclass Outlook windows using Windows API functions to inject your own form into the Explorer window. See [Adjacent Windows In Outlook](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stephen_griffin/archive/2010/06/01/adjacent-windows-in-outlook.aspx) for more information.

You can use the [WebViewURL][2] property of the Folder class which allows to set a string indicating the URL of the Web page that is assigned to a folder.

```
Sub SetupFolderHomePage()  
  Dim nsp As Outlook.NameSpace  
  Dim mpfInbox As Outlook.Folder  
  Dim mpfNew As Outlook.Folder 
  Set nsp = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")  
  Set mpfInbox = nsp.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)  
  Set mpfNew = mpfInbox.Folders.Add("MyFolderHomePage")  
  mpfNew.WebViewURL = "http://www.microsoft.com"  
  mpfNew.WebViewOn = True  
End Sub
```

Be aware, you need to set NonDefaultStoreScript key in the windows registry to get the WebView properties working in Outlook. See [You cannot add a URL to the Address box on the Home Page tab in Outlook 2007](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stephen_griffin/archive/2010/06/01/adjacent-windows-in-outlook.aspx) for more information.

As an alternative consider using the WebViewPane layout from ADX. The solution is based on the WebViewURL property and requires the windows registry key as well, but provides a more convinient way to set up a windows form with .net controls. See the [similar][3] forum thread for more information.

Also you can customize the current view in the explorer window. The Outlook object model provides the [CurrentView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861617(v=office.15).aspx) property for the Explorer and Folder classes. The View object represents a customizable view used to sort, group, and view data. Views are defined and customized using the View object's XML property. The XML property allows you to create and set a customized XML schema that defines the various features of a view.